# CAS & Spring Security --autoLogin

Tags: spring, security, cas

```
 spring security version: 3.1.0
 cas version: 3.1
```

If I have 2 system —— A and B. They are working successful in spring security cas.
     If I logged in A success, I had authentication info in system A. 
     And then I entered into B, I have no authentication, cause's the page which I browse is public.
     It doesn't trigger spring security's `AuthenticationExeception`. If I want to get authentication info in B, I have to access a link that is secure, then It will trigger spring security cas's authentication process.
My question:
whether can I get my cas authentication info If I access a public page.

Answer (score 0):

No, although you have login A system, but your authentication is not public in server side, just belong to current A system user **session**, if you login B system, there will generate a new sessionId, and spring security can not find SecurityContext matching such jsessionId in `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`, so it will return null.

finally, I don't think this question has any relation with `CAS`.